# How to change tab colors and tab text color of gtkdialog notebook

Tags: gtk

Hi is there a way to change tab and tab text colors for notebook in gtkdialog?

```
<notebook scrollable="true" enable-popup="true" show-border="false" labels="BBC|CNN|FOX|Sky News|Reddit|MSNBC|Discovery News|Market Watch|Business Insider|RTNews|Reuters|NDTV|TechCrunch|9GAG|LifeHacker|CommonDreams|TruthDig|Humour">
```

Comment: You will need CSS, which the gtkdialog tool does not seem to support yet. If you really want colored tabs, you'll need to consider switching to C (and GTK+ uses GtkBuilder, whose XML is very different from gtkdialog's).

Comment: thank you brother :) i will try or i will continue without colored tabs

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you can do something like:

```
GtkLabel *label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
gtk_label_set_markup (label, "<span color='red'>Text</span>");
gtk_notebook_set_tab_label (notebook, ..., label);
```

but I've not tested it.

Comment: The `gtkdialog` that the OP refers to is not `GtkDialog`, it's [a command line tool for building GUIs from an XML description](https://code.google.com/p/gtkdialog/) (the XML description is not GtkBuilder because it predates that). It's basically a very elaborate zenity, and from previous questions by this person they're trying to use it to add a GUI to a shell script. (I'd keep this answer anyway; it shows one possible way of doing it in C.)